# How I can export multer module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to export modul multer to another file but the console returns an error to me.

```
TypeError: uploadImg.single is not a function
```

here is my multer.js

```
module.export = () => {
    const multer = require("multer");
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination(req, file, cb) {
            const url = `./uploads/catalog`;
            cb(null, url);
        },
        filename(req, file, cb) {
            file.originalname = "re_" + file.originalname;
            cb(null, `${file.originalname}`);
        }
    });
    const uploadImg = multer({
        storage: storage
    });

    return uploadImg;
};
```

And here is a part of my routes file

```
const uploadImg = require("./../services/multer");
app.post("/catalog/upload/img", uploadImg.single("image"), async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.file);
});
```

Comment: try console.log(uploadImg) and see what inside

Comment: @Paweł Baca, Hi, I am facing same issue, How did you solve the issue ? Please share your complete code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in multer.js

You should write `module.exports =` instead of `module.export =`

Answer (score 4):

You start with this: `module.export = () => {...` which means that you export the function.

So `uploadImg` is the function `const uploadImg = require("./../services/multer");` and the only way how to call it is with `uploadImg()`.

If you have everything else correct then `uploadImg().single("image")` should do the trick, but then it does not make sense to export it as function. If you use it in static context (which routes are), then you probably want something like this:

```
const multer = require("multer");
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination(req, file, cb) {
        const url = `./uploads/catalog`;
        cb(null, url);
    },
    filename(req, file, cb) {
        file.originalname = "re_" + file.originalname;
        cb(null, `${file.originalname}`);
    }
});
const uploadImg = multer({
    storage: storage
});

exports.uploadImg = uploadImg;
```

Then you can call it as following

```
const myMulter = require("./../services/multer");
app.post("/catalog/upload/img", myMulter.uploadImg.single("image"), async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.file);
});
```

Comment: getting : TypeError: uploadImg.single is not a function

Comment: libik, you mentioned that the only way to call it was with uploadImg() which worked with the oroginal code, but the code you posted below, like with s4suryapal, also led me to "TypeError: uploadImg.single ".  

I just went back to the original code above with "exports" as the recommended answer suggested, and then used uploadImg() when calling it ---thanks, that saved me a lot of time. 

When I found this answer, I was looking for a way to have a separate middleware file for multer, so I got what I needed out of this thread.

Comment: @PaulW - when you use `exports.name` then when you requires it, you find that variable inside `name`. I added example how to call it, hopes it makes more sense now. Its basically similar as have `module.exports = { uploadImg: uploadImg }`